# maximum number of physical replication on one server

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-performance, master-slave-replication, postgresql-12

I have a server with `physical replication`. It has been working very well till now.
I follow the procedure here : https://linuxhint.com/setup-physical-replication-postgresql/ to create the replication.

Now I want to make another physical replication for the same master (so it is 1 master replicated onto 2 slaves).

Based on the previous experience, during `postgres service restart`, it takes 21 hours for the `replica` to be in synch with the master.

Before I start, how do I know if this master has reached it's performance limit? How can I find out?
Will the second physical replication take huge chunks out of performance?

Thanks